# Partial Fraction Using Heaviside cover-up method

Tags: partial-fractions

How to convert this equation into Partial fraction Using Heaviside Cover-up Method
$$\frac{x^2}{(x+2)(2x+3)}$$

After trying to solve this I am ending up getting this which is incorrect :
$$-\frac{4}{(x+2)}+\frac{9}{2(2x+3)}$$

Or is there any other way to get through.
refernce to the method :-
 
http://math.mit.edu/suppnotes/suppnotes03/h.pdf
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the power of $x$ is same in the numerator & the denominator

express it as $$A+\frac B{x+2}+\frac C{2x+3}$$ where $A,B,C$ are arbitrary constants

Then multiply out either sides by $(x+2)(2x+3)$ and compare the constants and the coefficients of $x,x^2$ to determine $A,B,C$

Clearly, $\displaystyle A=\frac1{2}$